# How can I get use the values of an object in order to define a new type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks like this

```
const codeMap: Record<string, number> = {
  level1: 1,
  level2: 2,
  level3: 3,
  level4: 4,
};
```

How can I create a type like the one below without having to list every value in the codeMap?

```
type codeMapValues = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate `codeMap` as `Record<string, number>` you are widening its type to the point where the compiler has no idea which particular property keys or values exist, other than to know that each value will be of type `number`.  If you want the compiler to remember the exact mapping, you should drop the annotation and use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to let it know that you actually expect `codeMap`'s values to stay put and not be changed via assignment, like `codeMap.level2 = 123` or something:

```
const codeMap = {
  level1: 1,
  level2: 2,
  level3: 3,
  level4: 4,
} as const;
```

Once you do that, you can use `typeof codeMap` to [query the type of the `codeMap` value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) and then [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) its property values:

```
type CodeMapValues = typeof codeMap[keyof typeof codeMap];
// type CodeMapValues = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKAmBTAsgQwA4wLwwN4CgYYAbRAN0WIEYAuGKgGkJPMoCY62mjSLiBmOv24s+AFjpimAXxioIccNADc+fFACe6RDADCIJGnQA1VMQCuiBTk3aQAM0WGMAbQDWiDQ5i3E3hCgYALqqAPShPlo6+s4mZpbW9DAAPjBsKTD8GWJAA)